# Is there a way to use the Python "with" statement like the "using" of C#

Tags: python

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480966/display-hourglass-when-application-is-busy) and it comes to my mind I needed it also, but in Python.
So I'm wondering if there is a way of doing that with the `with` statement in Python.

Basically what I want is some kind of IDisposable (C#) analogy in Python. I know, for sure it will be a little different, I think something like:

```
class ForUseInWith(IDisposableLike):
    #something here
    pass
```

and use it like this:

```
with ForUseInWith() as disposable:
    #something here
    pass
```

Currently I'm figuring out how to do this studying the [python reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and the [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), if I manage to do a good solution and a clever example I will post here the answer. But in the way maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to do, you just need to have an `__enter__` and an `__exit__` method in your class.

**Example:**

```
class ForUseInWith(object):

    def test(self):
        print 'works!'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

**Using It:**

```
>>> with ForUseInWith() as disposable:
    disposable.test()

works!
```

**Expanding It:**

You can of course, have an `__init__` method which receives parameters (like `open()` does) and you can also include ways of handling errors/exceptions in the `__exit__` method.  This kind of structure is best used for simple classes which also have a requirement to be able to be disposed, or be one-off processes that don't need to stick around or have complicated disposal

Comment: Just the example I'm looking for. And also I spot an error in my post.